# Space Opera Comic 80s/90s

Tags: story-identification, comics, space-opera

This might be a bit more complicated, because the comic I'm looking for is not well known, I think it was 4-5 issues, might have been from the late 80s, mid-90s, not sure about the publisher. Probably independent. I read it once a years ago but can't remember the name and my googling isn't turning anything up either.

So:

- The setting is feudal space opera. It reminded me strongly of the "Fading Suns" universe, a d20 roleplaying system.
- The main protagonist is a monk/priest-like character who is called to a planet to root out corruption (which he does very efficiently).
- Small detail I remember: Protagonist roughing up a pimp-like character, surprising him with his pendant that essentially is just the pommel-weight of a concealed kusari-gama-style weapon (weird detail to remember, I know).
- The comic's artistic style places it in the vicinity of 2000AD, Heavy Metal magazine, particularly Simon Bisley or Glenn Fabry.

Comment: It's in English, right? I found something not in English, but you probably found it too

Comment: Hey. Yeah I think it is in English. However, memory is a tricky thing, it has happened to me before that I could have sworn that I read something in English but it was in fact my other second language, German. Still curious though. What did you find?

Comment: Oh, "Tiamat - maîtrise de l'esprit" by Christophe Hermosilla, but that's in French, not German: https://books.google.com/books?id=_4izBgAAQBAJ and it may just be an RPG, not an actual comic book. Might be a start though?

Comment: I'll happily answer my own question. After some painstaking internet-combing I found the comic: "Shadow Empires: Faith Conquers" by Christopher Moeller. https://www.darkhorse.com/Comics/93-299/Shadow-Empires-Faith-Conquers-1-of-4. So, some of my original parameters were correct, some not. Dark Horse certainly isn't an indepedent publishers, also the aesthetics are probably closer to Warhammer 40k than the aforementioned Fading Suns. Anyway, thanks, barrycarter, for having a look.

Comment: @Fanderay Feel free to post this as the answer to your own question! This will stop your question appearing as "unanswered". :)

Answer (score 3):

As noted above, this is currently showing up as "unanswered".

"[Shadow Empires: Faith Conquers](https://www.darkhorse.com/Comics/93-299/Shadow-Empires-Faith-Conquers-1-of-4)", published in 1994, first part of the [Iron Empires](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Empires) series, by Christopher Moeller was identified by the querent as the correct comic.

[image: Shadow Empires: Faith Conquers - Comic book cover]

> In the far future, humanity is in decline, the soul-possessing Vaylen are advancing, and man's only hope is Faith...
>
> On the distant outpost planet of Hotok, warrior-priest Faith and his elite troop, the Grey Rats, fight a desperate two-front war -- the alien Vaylen invading from the stars, and the decay and corruption they find in Hotok society itself. Shadow Empires is a beautifully painted science fiction epic in the tradition of Robert A. Heinlein!

It involves a warrior priest, it came out in four issues, and it is a space opera.